# Exporting 25,000+ records to excel from database via HTTP

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel

Any idea how can I download excel file faster from database?

It should be on button click. I tried using this code below:

```
SqlConnection connSql = new SqlConnection(Generic);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand cmdSql = new SqlCommand();
cmdSql.Connection = connSql;
cmdSql.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


cmdSql.CommandText = "sp_GetDetails";

cmdSql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageIndex", 0));
cmdSql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize",rowcount));
cmdSql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@administratordid",     adminid));
connSql.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSql);
da.Fill(ds);

gvDetails.AllowCustomPaging = false;
gvDetails.AllowPaging = false;
gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
gvDetails.DataBind();
connSql.Close();

Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default; 
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

Response.ContentType = contentType;
    HtmlTextWriter objTW = new HtmlTextWriter(objSW);
gvDetails.RenderControl(objTW);
Response.Write(style); 
Response.Write(objSW);
Response.End();
```

It taking me like 10 mins to download the whole file. Number of rows I have on my database is 25,000.

Please suggest a faster method for this. I have been trying different codes but not working yet.

Comment: Does it also takes 10 minutes to run the query without making an export? If so the problem is in the stored procedure. Second, it looks your are trying to do two things at the same time (export and databinding to a gridview?)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rendering a table as HTML that the user downloads and excel tries to display, use a real excel file, you can generate it for example with [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

The code is simple, there's even a method: `LoadFromDataTable`:

```
try {
    var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet-Name");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(ds.Tables[0], true, TableStyles.Light18);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //log error
}
Response.End();
```